# Can a Windows Store app switch languages from Javascript to C#?

Tags: c#, javascript, windows-store

I've built a fairly simple packaged Javascript app for Windows Store. As I expand with more features I'm kind of wondering about whether I should have written it in c# instead.

Since the app is very simple I could quite easily re-write it in C# in a matter of days, however I don't know if existing users will be able to upgrade from the javascript version to the C# version. Is this possible?

Can a Windows Store app switch languages between versions, or is an app limited to whatever language it was originally written in?

Comment: This isn't a very clear question, however...My guess on what you are asking is no there isn't a way to automatically convert from JavaScript to C# (.Net) as one is client side and the other is server side.  Unless you are using Node.js or another JavaScript framework...But JavaScript and it's libraries are your friend you should use them.

Comment: If you are able to transform you app into c# code you should be able to replace the online package by simply uploading the new one. I don´t know about any restrictions that an updated package needs to be of the same language that the previous had

Comment: @abc123 windows store apps can be written in either c# or JavaScript. Both are client side. I'm not looking to convert one into the other, but replace my existing JavaScript app in the store with a c# one. I'm more wondering if its possible for the user to upgrade in this manner or does it have to be a separate, new app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an answer on the windows developer forums

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/3fbfa3cd-0f01-4913-9cbb-a4b6bf0518b3/switch-code-of-a-published-app-from-javascript-to-c

For anyone interested, it IS possible to switch between languages in app updates.